# How can use the 'show' function in Haskell with a custom type?

Tags: function, haskell, types, functional-programming

### How can i use 'show' function  with a type that i created?

I have these types:

```
type  Z      =  Integer
type  Var    =  String
type  State  =  Var -> Z
```

That represent a function Var -> Z,  this state help me to implement the while language.

An example of state (relation between variables and it value):

```
initState :: State
initState "x" = 3
initState "y" = 4
initState _ = 0
```

Right now i can show just the value of one of those variables (i.e. initState "x"  return the value of the variable "x", 3)

How can i show the state of each variable without knowledge about what variables are included in this state?

Comment: you cannot - maybe you want `type State = Map Var Z` instead then you can get to the contained keys

Comment: is posible with a show instance ??

Comment: you cannot write a (sensible) instance for functions - look at what you have - you have no chance of finding out if `"z"` is a value if you don't stick it in and test if it's `== 0` or something - and as there are infintely many strings ... well you get the idea

Comment: with maps your keys are part of the structure, so you *know* exactly what you put in - so of course you can show it easily

Comment: Thank you! I think that's the best way to do it!

Comment: Using `type` lets you define an alias. Its not a new type. To get a real new type use `newtype` or `data`. Then you can define instances for show for your new type, including types that consist of functions.

Comment: Why push this again with a strange *tag edit*? (There is no `algebraic-data-type` in this question)

Comment: You're right, i made a mistake... It wast for another post.